# Android authentication with MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql

i'm a new android app developer and this is my first app ... so the app should get information from the server database which is MySQL database and show to the users on there phones as a notifications. 
but first the user should enter a username & password and the app should connect to the database throw internet and check if the username & password are correct.
what i don't know here ( my question ) is how to make the android app connect on that database? i know how to use JSON but to connect on a database and check if those are the correct user credentials... i don't know how to do that.
so if you mind help me on my first real project , i would be very thankful

Comment: search for tutorials. this is quite a broad question to answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to make the android app connect to a MySQL database?"
The short answer is that you don't, well at least not directly.

I've been in your situation before. I had experience with Java and jdbc, and thought I could do something similar in Android. However, after many wasted days of trying to figure out the Android equivalent I came to the following realization:

> You do not, I repeat, do not connect directly from your Android app to
>   a database (not talking about the SQLite local storage).

There is a third piece that you might not have considered yet, and that is web services. You (or whoever knows enough about the database) will want to set up at least one (but probably a few) web services to expose data from the db. This way, your android app and/or any other app can use the data.

So the logic of the three-part system (app, web service, db) might looks something like this:

```
1)App sends a username and password to the webservice
2)Web service queries the db to see if username and password combination exist
   a) If exists, return success message (and maybe some other json data)
   b) Else If doesn't exist, return fail message 
   c) Else error, return error message
3)App handles response from web service
```

I'd recommend researching REST web services. If you are the one who will end up making the web services, I would also recommend researching security best practices as well so that someone doesn't come along and mess with your db.